# ReactJS: Pass object into fetch promise

Tags: reactjs, fetch, quill

I'm kind of new react, and this quill plugin is really confusing me. I'm using `react-quilljs` to display an editable rich text field, which is supposed to be pre-populated with a value retrieved using fetch from my API. Seems pretty simple, right? But I'm getting the error 'quill is undefined' in the fetch callback.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { useQuill } from "react-quilljs";
import "quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
import "quill/dist/quill.bubble.css";
// see https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quilljs

export default function View(props) {
  
  const [group, setGroup] = useState([]);
  const { quill, quillRef } = useQuill({});

  useEffect(() => {

      fetch('/api/groups/' + props.id , {
                method: 'GET'
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                
                setGroup(data);

                quill.setContents(JSON.parse(data));                
            })
            .catch(console.log);

    }, [quill]);

    return(
        
        <div >
            <div id="descriptionInput" ref={quillRef} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Of course I've omitted a lot of the code, but I think it should be enough to illustrate the problem. I think, basically the question is, how do I pass the quill object into the fetch promise?

I have searched for the answer but for some reason can't find anything on this.

Comment: have you considered trying https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill instead? it's much more robust and popular.

Comment: @buzatto Yes I originally started with react-quill, but then switched to react-quilljs because I was having problems with it as well :(

Comment: I'm not familiar with the quill library, but from the docs and the example [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quilljsbasic-wm0uk?file=/src/App.js), `console.log(quill);    // undefined > Quill Object`. I'm guessing you're getting the error as at the first few renders quill is undefined. Have you tried running `fetch` only if `quill` is defined? If this works, you can optimise it a bit to ensure that fetch happens right away then run `quill.setContents` only when it is defined.

Comment: @AsherLim That seems to make sense, but the hook is only getting called once. When I add the condition `if (quill)`, it never gets reached..

Answer (score 1):

I looked through the documents and found this:

```
quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML();
```

I have made a working sample for you:
https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-stonebraker-itt06?file=/src/App.js:401-469

Answer (score 0):

After some more inspection, it turns out `useEffect` is being called multiple times, and quill is not available right away (as Asher Lim notes). So adding a check `if (quill)` inside the fetch promise solves the problem.

Of course this means that the fetch is being done more times than necessary, which can be solved with some more refactoring.